# python3 for loop don't work with urlopen

Tags: python, bash, python-3.x, unix

I'm curently working on a program that reads the log error file and takes the file from command line argument then I have to print most repeating 25 errors.

For instance;
(this is a really large file so I will just copy & paste couple lines to make this clear)

```
[Sun Oct 09 14:15:52 2011] [error] [client 64.15.156.151] script '**/var/www/html/myip.php**' not found or unable to stat

[Sun Oct 09 14:16:25 2011] [error] [client 64.15.156.151] script '**/var/www/html/myip.php**' not found or unable to stat

[Sun Oct 09 14:18:42 2011] [error] [client 123.166.54.36] File does not exist: **/var/www/html/deny2**

[Sun Oct 09 14:26:48 2011] [error] [client 66.249.68.178] File does not exist: **/home/ms10694/public_html/homepage/Midterm Project/zengarden-sample.html**

[Sun Oct 09 14:29:59 2011] [error] [client 64.15.156.151] script '**/var/www/html/myip.php**' not found or unable to stat

[Sun Oct 09 14:30:23 2011] [error] [client 38.99.97.53] File does not exist: /var/www/html/robots.txt**

[Sun Oct 09 14:30:23 2011] [error] [client 38.99.97.53] File does not exist: **/var/www/html/favicon.ico**
```

I need to search in for loop those bolded addresses and find most repeating 25 errors.

My code searches for any line includes '/var.....+' but for some reason it does keep printing only very first ' /var...+ ' on log error file.
What am I missing here?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import urllib.request
import re
import sys
import os

Argument = sys.argv[1]

LogErrorFile = urllib.request.urlopen(Argument)

InBytes = LogErrorFile.read()

InString = InBytes.decode("utf8")

#for s in InString:
text = InString
for s in InString:
 FindLines = re.findall('/var.+', text)
 print (FindLines[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot going on here so I'll give you a slightly simplified version of what you're looking for:

```
import io
import re
from sys import argv

in_file = argv[1]

with io.open(in_file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as my_file:
  for line in my_file:
    print(re.findall('\/var.*', line))
```

> Why does it keep printing the first /var line?

Because you ask it to with the zero here:

```
FindLines[0]
```

It's not clear how you're defining "error" (whole line? just a piece?) so I'm not pulling the most common errors. And that type error file isn't usually retrieved remotely so I didn't include `urllib`. Instead I assumed it was local and used the `io` module.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you!
I had to use urllib so I went this way ;

I sent the error messages into dir so I could compare in there also I set the for loop on dic works as how it should be.